# Retrieving element IDs from external web pages

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, xss

I am trying to get a web page to print an element ID that has been clicked on (using an alert for now).

However, the web pages will be external sites (Google for example).

I have tried this with a new window and an iframe but cannot get the desired functionality.  Would appreciate help with my JS functions as I am new with this technology.

```
function windowOpen() {  
  myWindow=window.open("http://www.google.com",'','width=1000,height=700');
  myWindow.focus;

  var tag;
  onmouseclick = tag = "Element name: " + myWindow.event.srcElement.tagName + " ID: " + myWindow.event.srcElement.id;
  alert(tag);
}

function hideShow() {
  var myIframe = document.getElementById('myFrame');
  var content ;
  onmouseclick = tag = myIframe.contentDocument.element.id;
  alert(content);
}
```

Comment: you can't access with javascript, resources from other domains, this is called Same Origin Policy

Comment: You cannot access the DOM or any other resources of other web pages that are not hosted on your domain. It is against [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, [it is not possible to get the user's browser to tell you things about data from other websites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (i.e. keep your hands off my online banking).

The only way to do this from your own page would be to proxy the remote pages through your own server (and rewrite any relative URIs).

Alternatively, you could investigate writing a browser extension as this would have heightened privileges (since users must actively install them).

Comment: Thanks all, I have researched XSS now.  Appreciated your responses

Comment: Also, Quentin - I'm now thinking of creating a FF extension - are you or someone else able to recommend a good starting tutorial for this?  Thanks